# create a datagrid with a button click

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I would like to know if that is possible (in silverlight, c#), for example by clicking a button, a small and editable datagrid appear, and if I click again on the button another datagrid appears.

Comment: Try it and share your results. If you have a specific problem after that, we'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Just create an empty StackPanel in XAML, create a button and capture the button click event, create a DataGrid in C#, and add that DataGrid to the .Children collection of the aforementioned panel.

Comment: i did it, but now... can I drag and drop datagrids? because i want to create for example for small datagrids and posisionate them where i want